How to change permissions of file with unknown owner and group?
I changed the permissions of a directory recursively but a few files are unchanged because they have an unknown owner and group:
sudo chmod -R g+r /home/user/.local/share/waydroid/data/
ls -l /home/user/.local/share/waydroid/data/data/android.ext.services/
ls: cannot access '/home/user/.local/share/waydroid/data/data/android.ext.services/cache': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/home/user/.local/share/waydroid/data/data/android.ext.services/code_cache': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? cache
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? code_cache

rsync fails to read these files with unknown owners:
rsync: [sender] readlink_stat("/home/user/.local/share/waydroid/data/user_de/0/org.lineageos.overlay.accent.red/cache") failed: Permission denied (13)

